# Get Pixel Data out of Byte Array of Bitmap

Tags: c#, screenshot, sharpdx

i'm mashing my head against the following problem:

I found a class around here which captures the screen with SharpDX. It fires an event and gives me a byte array of the bitmap.
Following class delivers the array:

```
try
{
    SharpDX.DXGI.Resource screenResource;
    OutputDuplicateFrameInformation duplicateFrameInformation;

    // Try to get duplicated frame within given time is ms
    duplicatedOutput.AcquireNextFrame(5, out duplicateFrameInformation, out screenResource);

    // copy resource into memory that can be accessed by the CPU
    using (var screenTexture2D = screenResource.QueryInterface<Texture2D>())
        device.ImmediateContext.CopyResource(screenTexture2D, screenTexture);

    // Get the desktop capture texture
    var mapSource = device.ImmediateContext.MapSubresource(screenTexture, 0, MapMode.Read, SharpDX.Direct3D11.MapFlags.None);

    // Create Drawing.Bitmap
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        var boundsRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

        // Copy pixels from screen capture Texture to GDI bitmap
        var mapDest = bitmap.LockBits(boundsRect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        var sourcePtr = mapSource.DataPointer;
        var destPtr = mapDest.Scan0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            // Copy a single line 
            Utilities.CopyMemory(destPtr, sourcePtr, width * 4);

            // Advance pointers
            sourcePtr = IntPtr.Add(sourcePtr, mapSource.RowPitch);
            destPtr = IntPtr.Add(destPtr, mapDest.Stride);
        }

        // Release source and dest locks
        bitmap.UnlockBits(mapDest);
        device.ImmediateContext.UnmapSubresource(screenTexture, 0);

        //bitmap.Save("sample.bmp"); // Das geht!

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ScreenRefreshed?.Invoke(this, ms.ToArray());
            _init = true;

        }
        //_init = true; // Zsmhang: bitmap.Save
    }
    screenResource.Dispose();
    duplicatedOutput.ReleaseFrame();
}
catch (SharpDXException e)
{
    if (e.ResultCode.Code != SharpDX.DXGI.ResultCode.WaitTimeout.Result.Code)
    {
        logger.Error(e.Message);
        logger.Error(e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

So i get an MemoryStream byte Array and i'm totally unsure how to get the Pixel Data out of it. I found many similar posts but noone ever seemed to correctly get the data out of such an linear array. I tried many variants, f.e.:

```
private void newFrameProcessing(object sender, byte[] data)
{
    logger.Debug("Frame Tick! ");

    Color clr = Color.Empty;

    // Get color components count (BGRA)
    int cCount = 4;

    int y = 0;

    // Get start index of the specified pixel
    for (int x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
    {
        int f = ((y * 1280) + x) * cCount;

        if (f > data.Length - cCount)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        byte b = data[f];
        byte g = data[f + 1];
        byte r = data[f + 2];
        byte a = data[f + 3]; // a
        clr = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);

        logger.Debug("GetPixel("+x+","+y+") : index-f = " + f + " RGB: " + clr.R + " " + clr.G + " " + clr.B);
    }
}
```

But that seems to assume that the first pixel is at the start of the array. I've tried to print the array to look whats in it, and it seems that the first bytes in the array are some kind of random stuff (maybe bitmap header or something?) and not exactly the correct pixel.
If i save the Bitmap into a .bmp file (see commented line before event firing) i can see the correct screenshot, but things like the folder names are missing, is that normal?

So my questions are:

1. How to i get the correct pixel data out of the linear array? maybe i need the stride? but i dont know where this would help
2. the code i found isnt using Marshal.Copy, which seems to be a wide accepted way to get pixel data. Would that be better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to do, just get an 1d array of pixel data as int or Color?, or do you want to be able to loop over via x and y or something

Comment: The goal will be to call my own GetPixel(x,y) upon that array to process the pixel (and forward it to a LED, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(fromPath))
{   
  // lock the array for direct access int 32Bpp
  var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

  // store the max length so we don't have to recalculate it
  var length = (int*)data.Scan0 + bmp.Height * bmp.Width;

  for (var p = (int*)data.Scan0; p < length; p++)           
  {          
     //*p is your pixel as an int;

     // change the color like this
     *p = Color.Red.ToArgb();
     Color = Color.FromArgb(*p);
  }

  // or if you want x/y
  var p = (int*)data.Scan0;

  for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
     for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
        *(p + x + y * bmp.Width) = Color.Red.ToArgb();

  // if you want to copy the whole array 
  int[] managedArray = new int[bmp.Width * bmp.Height];
  Marshal.Copy((int*)data.Scan0, managedArray, 0, bmp.Width * bmp.Height); 

  // unlock the bitmap
  bmp.UnlockBits(data);
}
```

***Note*** : Totally untested

Lastly, when a bitmap is stored in a 1d array, the first row of pixels are stored, then immediately afterwards is the next row of pixels.

So if you want to know where you are at anyone time within a single index, you just 2 for loops

```
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
   for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
      // your pixel is at array[x + y * width]
```

Comment: Seems like i'm not able to fully understand your answer, but i appreciate your effort, thank you! So the thing is I already have an one-dimensional array with the whole bitmap data (as far as i understand the class) when the event fires. So when i now just want to get a specific pixel, do i need to create a new bitmap and marshal copy it all again?

Comment: And secondly, is it possible your last lines didnt take into account that one pixel isnt just at one index because it consists of 4 bytes each? (r,g,b,a)

Comment: In regards to the first question, if you have already got the array, and its 1 dimensional, if you dont need to refresh that data, no you dont have to do that all again. your pixel is at `array[x + y * width]`

Comment: i cant assure everything i wrote is correct as it was all just written into the post. however it should be good. 1 int = 1 pixel, your array size = `width * height`

Comment: Okay thank you, it seems i got the first answer! But secondly, If I just call the pixel at 'array[x + y * width]', i will just get the blue byte of the rgba pixel, due to having the 32bppargb format.

Comment: 32bppargb will give you a whole pixel returned in an `int*`